# Is there a way to obtain the HTML of a web page using the .NET compact framework?

Tags: .net, compact-framework, html

As the WebBrowser control does not expose a get accessor for the DocumentText property you cannot use it to obtain the HTML that was loaded into this control. Does anyone know a way to obtain the HTML as a string?

I am using .NET CF3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class. [Here](http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/HttpWebFetch.aspx) is an example on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried WebBrowser.Document?

```
System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument document = this.webBrowser1.Document;
```

It's exposed as:

[BrowsableAttribute(false)]
public HtmlDocument Document { get; }

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the  [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)?