# web browser windows mobile 6.5 read input text

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-6.5

I'm using web browser to open a connection with Windows Mobile 6.5, however when I tried to read the value from the input text, I can not do this.

The way I open the web browser is the following:

> webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.something.com"));
>
> webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new
>   webBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);

Is there another way to do this, with no webBrowser??

What I tried with no luck, for handle the html content  is the following:

> System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument document =
>   this.webBrowser1.Document; 
>   document.All["userName"].GetAttribute("value")))

It seems that even adding the reference to System.Windows.Forms in my solution, I'm not able to do it so.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate question, same as in [Is there a way to obtain the HTML of a web page using the .NET compact framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870028/is-there-a-way-to-obtain-the-html-of-a-web-page-using-the-net-compact-framework) and different ones at stckoverflow.

You can not access the content of the html inside the webbrowser control. There are some workarounds like using HttpWebRequest and then load the result into the webbrower component to show to user. See also http://anoriginalidea.wordpress.com/2007/05/31/the-net-20-compact-framework-webbrowser-control/ and http://anoriginalidea.wordpress.com/?s=webby (serach results for webby".

There also weired workarounds using custom ActiveX that invokes into managed code and vice versa.

Javascript is a client side scripting code. why should one use the webbrowser control to control this javascript. It should be handled by the html/javascript code itself.

So, what is your intention?

Comment: Than you by your reply, what I want to do is to open a ie browser in the Windows Mobile app, once the app loads, this URL  refers to a site which is used to log in the user then after validating that their credentials are correct, I want to get the user name and use it into my app. So the main issue I'm having is to get the user name from the form into the web page that URL's loads and get the user name after user entered into the input text, just a document.getElementById("username"), if it would be javascript. 
Kindest Regards

Comment: You can use a form with input name and password and then a webrequest against the web server to validate the input. In this way you have full control on the user name supplied and the positive or negative webresponse.

Comment: Thank you so much @josef I'm going to try this option too.